# Using an infinitive-with-to after an Auxiliary verb in a UN official code, permitted?

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives

We are not permitted to bring an infinitive-with-to after auxiliary verbs. However, in the following it seems this rule has been broken. You see after *should*, *to recognize* has come. Is this right?

> Stakeholders in tourism development and tourists themselves **should** observe the social and cultural traditions and practices of all peoples, including those of minorities and indigenous peoples and **to recognize** their worth. ([Source](http://dtxtq4w60xqpw.cloudfront.net/sites/all/files/docpdf/gcetbrochureglobalcodeen.pdf))

Would someone please explain what has happened here?

Comment: I think it's an error. You're right that we should not use infinitive with "to" here, but given the long (i.e. complex) sentence, the writer has lost track of the original modal verb "should".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is probably grounded in a mistake.

Comment: I agree that the example sentence is in error, but I don't believe that necessarily makes it off-topic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the rule is correct; this is clearly an error in the original document.  It should be

> Stakeholders in tourism development and tourists themselves should observe the social and cultural traditions and practices of all peoples, including those of minorities and indigenous peoples, and recognize their worth.

Whoever edited the document prior to publication just missed this mistake.